# MATLAB interp2 function in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to use interp2 function of MATLAB in Julia.

I tried GR module but I failed.

Now I'm using julia 0.64 version

Hope you guys can help me

Comment: Please refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should ask a question about your problem with `interp2` from the `GR.jl` package. Yet it is always worth noting that another option is to use Python's function via the `PyCall` module: `@pyimport scipy.interpolate as interpolate` and now you can use the interpolation functions from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Interpolations.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Interpolations.jl). This example is equivalent to the  `interp2` function:

```
A = rand(8,20)
knots = ([x^2 for x = 1:8], [0.2y for y = 1:20])
itp = interpolate(knots, A, Gridded(Linear()))
itp(4,1.2)  # approximately A[2,6]
```

http://juliamath.github.io/Interpolations.jl/latest/control/#Gridded-interpolation-1

Answer (score -1):

You might find the [Dierckx.jl](https://github.com/kbarbary/Dierckx.jl) package helpful to achieve 2-d spline fitting. See for instance `Spline2D`.